# Как сделать виджет ListWheelScrollView круглым?

Tags: flutter, dart

Как сделать виджет **ListWheelScrollView** круглым и возможно ли такое? Я сделал кргуглым виджет **Container**

```
Container(
 decoration: BoxDecoration(
  color: Colors.amber,
  shape: BoxShape.circle,
 )
),
```

и поместил в него **ListWheelScrollView**, теоретически список не должен вылезать за пределы своего родителя и должен стать круглым или нет? Далее, часть разаметки и фото.

```
Container(
 decoration: BoxDecoration(
  color: Colors.amber,
  shape: BoxShape.circle,
 ),
 child: Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
  child: ListWheelScrollView(

   itemExtent: 50, //height / высота
   squeeze: 1.0, //divider / разделитель
   diameterRatio: 2.0, //diameter / сотношение
   offAxisFraction: 0.0, //bias / смещение +to left -to right

   onSelectedItemChanged: (index) {
    setState(() {
     _ara.forEach( (value) => value.isSelected = false );
     _ara[index].isSelected = true;
     _str = '${_ara[index].data}';
    });
   },

   children: <Widget>[
    for(int i=0; i<_ara.length; i++)
     _getItemList(context, i)
   ],

  ),
 ),
),
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**main.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return MaterialApp(
   debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
   title: 'Name App',
   theme: ThemeData(
    primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
   ),
   home: Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
     title: Text('Name Page'),
    ),
    body: MyHomePage(),
   ),
  );
 }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
 @override
 _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

 List< ItemListData<String> > _ara;

 double _height;
 double _width;
 TextStyle _textStyle;

 String _str;

 @override
 void initState() {
  super.initState();

  _ara = _populateData(20);

  _width = double.infinity;
  _height = double.infinity;
  _textStyle = TextStyle(
   color: Colors.white,
   fontSize: 20.0,
   fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
  );

  _str = '';

 }

 @override
 void dispose() {
  super.dispose();

 }

 void _f1() {
  setState(() {

  });
 }

 //метод возвращает коллекцию, которая была заполнена объектами класса ItemListData<String>
 //method returns a collection which was filled the objects of the cllass ItemListData<String>
 List _populateData(int amount) {
  List< ItemListData<String> > ara = [];
  for(int i = 0; i<amount; ) {
   i++;
   ara.add( ItemListData<String>('$i') );
  }
  return ara;
 }

 //метод возвращает элемент прокручиваемого списка
 //method returns an element of the scrolling list
 //Widget _getItemList(BuildContext context, int index) {}
 Widget _getItemList(_, index) =>
  Container(
   width: _width,
   height: _height,
   color: _ara[index].isSelected ? Colors.pink : Colors.cyan,
   alignment: Alignment.center,
   child: Text(
    '${_ara[index].data}',
    style: _textStyle,
   ),
  );

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Column(
   mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
   mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
   children: <Widget>[
    Expanded(
     flex: 1,
     child: Container(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      child: Text(
       _str,
       style: TextStyle(
        color: Colors.pink,
        fontSize: 36.0
       ),
      ),
     ),
    ),
    Expanded(
     flex: 1,
     child: Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
       color: Colors.amber,
       shape: BoxShape.circle,
      ),
      child: Padding(
       padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
       child: ListWheelScrollView(

        itemExtent: 50, //height / высота
        squeeze: 1.0, //divider / разделитель
        diameterRatio: 2.0, //diameter / сотношение
        offAxisFraction: 0.0, //bias / смещение +to left -to right

        onSelectedItemChanged: (index) {
         setState(() {
          _ara.forEach( (value) => value.isSelected = false );
          _ara[index].isSelected = true;
          _str = '${_ara[index].data}';
         });
        },

        children: <Widget>[
         for(int i=0; i<_ara.length; i++)
          _getItemList(context, i)
        ],

       ),
      ),
     ),
    ),
   ],
  );
 }
}

//данные, которые будут отображаться в элементе списка
//data which will be shown in the item of the list
class ItemListData<T> {
 bool isSelected = false;
 T data;
 ItemListData(this.data);
}
```

Comment: А он не выходит, он его растягивает. Покажите код `_getItemList`

Comment: Я привел вверху код.

Comment: Там код круга...

Comment: это первый код, во вотором коде в круг вложен код списка

Comment: А мне нужен код элемента списка (прямоугольник с индексом) `_getItemList`

Comment: изменил вопрос, в конце добавил весь код

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Накидал в какую сторону надо смотреть, дальше сами...

```
Expanded(
  flex: 1,
  child: ClipOval(
    clipper: CircleRevealClipper(),
    child: Container(
      color: Colors.amber,
      child: ListWheelScrollView(
        itemExtent: 50, //height / высота
        squeeze: 1.0, //divider / разделитель
        diameterRatio: 2.0, //diameter / сотношение
        offAxisFraction: 0.0, //bias / смещение +to left -to right
        ...
      ),    
    ),
  ),
),

class CircleRevealClipper extends CustomClipper<Rect> {
  @override
  Rect getClip(Size size) {
    var center =
        size.center(Offset.zero); // Offset(size.width / 2, size.height / 2);
    var radius =
        math.min(center.dx, center.dy); // min(size.width / 2, size.height / 2);

    return Rect.fromCircle(center: center, radius: radius);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper<Rect> oldClipper) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: Уважаемый MiT, огромное Вам спасибо!